# Xamrin.Forms Navigation.PopAsync not changing page on android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a login button, which when clicked triggers this method:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new SiteSelectionPage(), this);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

On iOS it works fine and the new page and title appear. On Android the title of the page changes from "Login" to "Site Selection" (which is what I want), but the content does not change at all (the username and password Entry boxes are still on the page).

Does anyone know why this is happening specifically on Android?

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in your code that you are trying to login the user, so what you can try is changing the App.MainPage in stead of doing that:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SiteSelectionPage());
```

Then if you want to remember if the user is already logged in you can try storing a Setting with this NuGet Package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/